# Allow Show in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

```
isoth = ContourPlot[ {v p } , {v, .12, 2}, {p, .12, 2}]
adiab = ContourPlot[ {v^1.4  p} , {v, .12, 2}, {p, .12, 2}]
Show[{isoth, adiab}, PlotRange -> All]
```

In an attempt to see heat/work thermodynamics in a Carnot cycle, could not plot hyperbolae type curves together. Please help to Show how the first plot can be made transparent when superimposed on the second and also how to refine level differences say to one fourth the present given default value.

EDIT1:

RegionPlot per Jose Antonio's suggestion for chosen constants

[image]

Comment: Add the option `, ContourShading -> False` for the contour plots.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you want, you may use e.g. `Contours -> 20,` to refine level differences

Comment: Thanks Both fixes have been helpful. Any given  answer I accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the equations of your adiabatics and isothermals, you can use:

```
isoth1 = 1; 
adiab1 = 1; 
isoth2 = 1.5; 
adiab2 = 1.5; 
RegionPlot[v p > isoth1 && v^(1/4) p > adiab1 && v p < isoth2 && v^(1/4) p < adiab2,
{v, .12, 2.5}, {p, .12, 2.5}, PlotPoints -> 100,
FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"V", "P"}), RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: RegionPlot .Yes looking for that exactly, before going in for ContourPlot !